# Can't find teachers lounge?

Tags: support, chat, teachers-lounge

Thank you, Robert, for hosting a moderators' chat at a time that's not 1AM where I am!

The [link in the email that I received](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/4/teachers-lounge?tab=schedule), however, is returning a "Page not found" message, and the *Teachers' Lounge* isn't anywhere to be found, either:

[image: screenshot of link showing 'page not found' message]

Am I doing something wrong, or am I just blind? The chat has changed a lot since I was last there!

Comment: You should be able to view the room now.

Comment: It looks like someone has granted you explicit access now.

Comment: @Marc - thanks, its all good, I've updated my profile "correctly" so now it all looks proper.

Comment: @Marc - that was me. It was discussed on chat last night with Robert. I've just removed Farseeker from the white list so it's just his moderator status that's letting him in.

Comment: The more important question, even almost 13 years later: why have Picard, Riker, and Worf been defaced?

Comment: @Joachim I have no earthly way of remembering. I was probably just bored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on your Server Fault profile on chat.SE. It looks like they stopped the practice of adding accounts to the access list, since all the SE mods are also chat mods and can access the room no matter what. Go to [your profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2860/mark-henderson) and switch your parent user to Webmasters, and you should be able to get in. If you want to stay on your SF profile you can add yourself to the [access list](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/4/teachers-lounge?tab=access)

Comment: @Farseeker Just to point out - you should change your chat profile to point to the parent site you're a mod on (Web Masters). There really shouldn't be anyone on the access list for the Teachers Lounge. We're discussing it right now

Comment: @Chris - thanks, I've done that and now I can access the link. Thanks heaps.