# Teacher's Lounge inaccessible for Stack Overflow Moderators

Tags: support, status-completed, chat, moderators, teachers-lounge

I tried to access the Teacher's Lounge (Stack Exchange Moderator Chat), but it says I must request access. Another moderator on Stack Overflow has also had the same thing happen to him (late yesterday).  Is this a bug or has something changed?

Comment: check your chat parent user, those get reset to a random site occasionally and if your parent user isn't on a site where you are a mod, you don't have access to restricted chat rooms.

Comment: @MadScientist I did that. After I did that it said my request was being processed.  I can now get into the TL; but at large it's still helpful to note that either there's a bug (randomly changing someone's parent site), or something else that could potentially happen again.  As it stands there's another moderator who still can't access the TL.

Comment: Yeah, there was some strangeness going on yesterday (I was definitely hit by it).  When I tried to reset the parent site for my chat user to Stack Overflow, it set my parent site to Area 51...  Another moderator on another site had to set my parent parent site back.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas Same thing happened to me.  KHAN!!!

Comment: @GeorgeStocker [KHAAAAAAANNNNNNN!!!!!!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlY7YnWvZBU)

Comment: Probably the same issue as: [Access denied on TL, what gives?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126112/access-denied-on-tl-what-gives)

Answer (score 4):

This issue has been resolved for me, though I'm not sure exactly how it was resolved. Here's why:

- I clicked 'request access'
- I [then noticed my'parent site' had changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72369/cant-find-teachers-lounge) (not by me) from Stack Overflow to Area 51.
- I changed it back, and tried accessing the Teacher's lounge again. No dice.
- I waited a few minutes, did a hard refresh of the page, and then saw the Teacher's Lounge Pop up for me.

Unknowns:

Was this fixed because someone gave me access to the TL? Or did the change from Area 51 -> Stack Overflow take a few minutes to work?

This has happened to other Moderators: Is this a bug in the site internals? Or a one time change due to *x*?

Comment: IIRC they (ie: balpha) are changing how chat accounts and the whole association thing work.

Comment: I believe also, to add to the previous comment, that they are doing this so they can use your profile to show your associated chat user, because it may be associated with another site, for when you need to find someone on chat. This also deals with the conflict of superpinging someone who already has a chat.se account with a @@id@othersite.se.com ping, whereby creating two chat users for the same overall account.